# Gremlin date operation:

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have below mentioned data set.

`g.addV('Person').property(id,'p1').property(single,'event_date','2023-08-31')`

How the gremlin query that check for if event_date is within 30 days of current date will look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Gremlin today does not have functions that allow mathematical operations on dates, so you cannot say something like "today minus 30 days". However, you can compare dates using the Gremlin `datetime` function. For example:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Person').has('event_date',between(datetime('2023-08-15'),datetime('2023-08-31')))
```

and

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Person').has('event_date',lte(datetime('2023-08-31')))
```

For that to work you would need to have created the vertex using

```java
g.addV('Person').property(id,'p1').property(single,'event_date',datetime('2023-08-31'))
```

An alternative approach would be to store the dates using 10 or 13 digit epoch integers. That way you could do addition and subtraction on the property values directly.